# Is finishing an in place mergesort algorithm with insertion sort possible/viable?

Tags: java, mergesort, insertion-sort

I have written an in place mergesort algorithm for sorting a large set of data of random size (100,000 elements or more). I was thinking about putting in insertion sort for when the data is  almost sorted to make the algorithm run a little bit faster. I was wondering if this is possible with in place mergesort?

Here is some of my code.

```
public static void merge(ArrayList<String> list, int low, int high) {
   if (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge(list, low, mid);
        merge(list, mid + 1, high);
        mergeSort(list, low, mid, high);
    }

}

public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> list, int first, int mid,
        int last) {
    int left = first;
    int right = mid + 1;
    String holder = "";

    // if mid <= mid+1 skip merge
    if (compareTo(list.get(mid), list.get(right)) <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    while (left <= mid && right <= last) {
        // if left index <= right index then just add to left
        if (compareTo(list.get(left), list.get(right)) <= 0) {
            left++;
        } else {
            holder = list.get(right);
            copyList(list, left, right - left);//moves everything from left to right-left                       up one index in the arraylist
            list.set(left, holder);

            left++;
            mid++;
            right++;
        }
    }
    // what is left is in place

}

public static void copyList(ArrayList<String> source, int srcPos, int length) {
    String temp1 = "";
    String temp2 = source.get(srcPos);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp1 = source.get(srcPos + 1);
        source.set(srcPos + 1, temp2);
        temp2 = temp1;
        srcPos++;
    }
}
```

Now, I was thinking of implementing Insertion sort by counter the number of elements when I first throw them into the arraylist and then changing my merge method to the following.

```
public static void merge(ArrayList<String> list, int low, int high) {
   if(high-low==dataSize-1){
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge(list, low, mid);
        merge(list, mid + 1, high);
        insertionSort(list);
   }else if (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge(list, low, mid);
        merge(list, mid + 1, high);
        mergeSort(list, low, mid, high);
    }

}
```

However, this actually makes my algorithm to take an eternity. Im guessing I'm doing this wrong and the algorithm is taking n^2 to run since the data is completely randomly generated and no where close to almost sorted.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? My guess is since its in place merge-sort it wont work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such algorithms are complicated and easy to get wrong. I implemented something very similar: an [in-place stable merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#cite_note-3). It also uses insertion sort for small sub-lists. I suggest to have a look at the [source code](http://h2database.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/dev/sort/InPlaceStableMergeSort.java) and compare it with what you are doing. You might also be interested in a [in-place stable quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#cite_ref-14).

Unless I'm mistaken your implementation is not stable (it might re-arrange elements that are equal). Depending on the use case, this may or may not be a problem.

Also, it seems your implementation is O(n^2) because the copyList method is O(n) and it is called n times.

About the insertionSort: what is `dataSize` and why do you compare it using equals? Don't you want to use `<` instead? If you do, the `else if (low < high)` is redundant (it is always true).